# How to configure sbt/ScalaTest to load test config from dependent project?

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, scalatest

I'm having trouble with `sbt test` not applying the test config of a dependent project. I have project A, which has a `src/main/resources/application.conf` and `src/test/resources/application.conf`. The intent is for the settings in the latter `application.conf` to have precedence in test. And this holds; when I run tests in project A, the test configuration is applied.

I have a project B in a separate directory which has a dependency declared on project A. When I run tests from project B, the settings in project A's `src/test/resources/application.conf` file are *not* applied.

It looks like the issue is caused by the order of the items on the classpath. When I run the tests in project A, I see `.../projecta/target/scala-2.11/test-classes/` comes before `.../projectA/target/scala-2.11/classes/`, but when I run the tests in project B, the order of those two directories is reversed.

I have created a [small sample project](https://github.com/mikem/sbt-scalatest-dependent-project) demonstrating this issue.

Comment: Did you report this as a bug by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

I had same demand in my test code and in my case, `ConfigFactory.parseFile()` worked well for me.

```
  val confFile = new File("src/test/resources/application.conf")
  implicit val config: Config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(confFile)
```

Does that work for your case?